# Storing large videos on the Server

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, storage

In my application the client is uploading relatively large videos, average is 500 MB. I have to encode the video in the backend to reduce the size, and I'm trying to use ffmpeg for that. However, ffmpeg needs around 10 minutes for each video, and I should be able to serve the video to the client instantly, or, at least in a few seconds after the upload is finished.

What would be the best practice in this context?

Comment: set their expectations - even youTube etc don't make a HQ version available immediately. if they want to see something within a very short timeframe either play back what they've uploaded while you re-encode, or do a first pass in ffmpeg that's very low quality but optimized for speed and then reprocess the asset again to the quality you want for long term use.

Comment: Horizontally scaling video encoding is extremely difficult. There are no open source or free projects that I am aware of that can do this. I suggest you use a service like [mux](https://mux.com) that does this by default.